# Defining Cache Size on User's Input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have using the following code to set the Cache Size according to the User's Input

```
int size=1024;
Console::WriteLine("Select the Cache Size.\n a. 1 Kb \n b. 2 Kb \n c. 4 Kb \n d. 8 Kb\n");
    String^ CACHE_SIZEoption = Console::ReadLine();
    //Char wh=CACHE_SIZEoption->ToChar();


    switch(CACHE_SIZEoption[0])
    {case 'a':{
        size= 1024;
        break;}

    case 'b':{
        size=2048;
        break;}

    case 'c':{size= 4096;
        break;}

    case 'd':{size=8192;
        break;}
    default: {Console::WriteLine("Wrong Input");}

    }

#define CACHE_SIZE size
long tags[CACHE_SIZE];
```

The error is produced on the last line, "long tags[CACHE_SIZE]"

```
expected constant expression
 cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
```

Please tell if there is another way to do this thing

Answer (score 3):

Arrays must have a compile-time fixed sizes. As you can see, your `size` variable can vary at run-time depending on the value of `CACHE_SIZEoption[0]`. Instead, you should use a run-time sized container, such as `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<long> tags(size);
```

Note that your `#define` probably isn't doing what you expect it to. Macros are expanded in the preprocessing stage. If you use `CACHE_SIZE` anywhere else in your code, it will be replaced with `size` before your code is compiled. If there is no `size` variable in those places, you'll get an error. It *does not* set `CACHE_SIZE` to be the value of `size` at that point in your code.

Comment: I have used this std::vector<long> tags[size]; giving errors error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @HanyaIdrees You need to `#include <vector>` and note that it's `(size)` not `[size]`. You pass the size to its constructor.

Comment: @HanyaIdrees By doing `std::vector<long> tags(size);`. You should get a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/150634).

Comment: @HanyaIdrees Well then you're trying to access an element that is not in your vector. That is, you're doing `tags[i]` where `i` is greater than `size-1`.

Comment: and what is my vector, i have not defined any vector individually, rather then you given line of code

Comment: @HanyaIdrees Exactly. That vector. `tags` is now a `std::vector<long>` rather than an array of `long`. It behaves like an array though, so you can still go `tags[i]`. However, you're accessing outside of its bounds, which is why you get the runtime error.

Comment: @HanyaIdrees By not accessing outside its bounds.

Comment: size has four option, as mentioned in above code, if they out of range

Comment: @HanyaIdrees `size` determines how many elements your vector `tags` will have. You can't access an element that is outside this `size`. That is what you are doing to get the runtime error. For example, if `size` is `1024`, you'll get an error if you do `tags[2000]` because there is no `2000`th element. As I said, please get a good C++ book. You seem to be in over your head.

Comment: i have included more code, where it seems the error is coming, please will you see it

Comment: @HanyaIdrees I have reverted your question back to its original form. Please post a new question if you want to ask about this. Changing the question makes the existing answers not make sense any more.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `#define` that's a preprocessor directive and not part of the C++ language. The preprocessor is run before the compiler and does simple text replacements.

What your compiler will see is

```
long tags[size];
```

And that is a [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and is not supported in C++.